# disable timeouts for junit test

Tags: java, junit

I need to disable the timeouts for a long running junit test, but nothing I'm trying is working correctly.

First, I tried extending the timeout to an extremely long time using the following.

```
@Test(timeout = Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

Theoretically, this should have extended the timeout to a number of milliseconds equivalent to about 292 million years, but the test still timed out after around 300 minutes.

Next, I tried the following:

```
@Rule
public TestRule timeout = new DisableOnDebug(new Timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

If I run the tests without debug mode, they timeout in about 20 seconds.  That's expected.  But, even under debug mode, I'm still seeing timeouts after around 300-400 minutes (never the same).  I don't know *where* this timeout is firing or what timeout is firing:

Here's an excerpt of the timeout:

```
[junit] Testcase: myTest took 0.002 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] Timeout occurred. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the timeout.
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Timeout occurred. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the timeout.
[junit]     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

What could be the cause of this?  How can I just *disable* the timeouts completely?

*Update*: I should note that without specifying the timeout via annotation or rule, I'm still seeing the timeout as well.

Comment: Why are you using timeouts at all? The time can essentially vary depending on the environment where tests are running. It may depend on CPU power available, on its load in particular moment, on RAM, on network, etc. A good alternative is to set up monitoring and define the acceptable duration for all tests. If the limit is exceeded, the monitoring should alert you.

Comment: Well, it *appears* to have a default timeout, because I'm seeing the errors without the annotation as well.  I'll update the question to state that.